# Maximal and minimal element in preordered set

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Generally the notion of maximal and minimal element is defined in a partially ordered set (binary relation is reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive).

A preorder is a binary relation that is reflexive and transitive.

Can we define the notion of maximal and minimal element in a preordered set?

Comment: Sure you can, the same way you do in a poset: $x$ is maximal if $x\leq y$ implies $x=y$. However, it will not generally have the properties you might want. For example, in the total pre-order on a set with more than one element, there are no maximal elements.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Why not define $x$ is maximal if $x\le y$ implies $y\le x$? I.e., $x$ is maximal if there is no $y$ such that $x\lt y$.

Comment: @bof: again, you can, but it may not have the properties that you "expect"/"hope". The real question is: what do you want these elements to do in a preorder (and more especially, do you want them to behave in certain ways when you mod out by the equivalence to get an order)?

Comment: Both notions are the same. Let $(X,\preceq)$ be a preordered set. Define ${\prec}:={\preceq}\setminus id_X$, where $id_X=\{(x,x):x\in X\}$. Fix $S\subseteq X$. Fix $t\in S$.The following are equivalent (i) $(\forall s\in S)[t\preceq s\:\Rightarrow\:t=s]$ (ii) $\neg(\exists s\in S)[t\prec s]$.

Comment: @bof: The advantage of (i) over (ii) is that it is written in terms of $\preceq$ instead of $\prec$. The advantage of (i) over "$x\le y$ implies $y\le x$" is that (ii) is the standard definition for $R$-minimal elements, where $R$ is a well-founded binary relation.

Comment: @AlbertoTakase The standard definition of $x\lt y$ for a quasi-ordering $\le$ (e.g., the ordering of linear order types by embeddability) is $x\le y\land y\not\le x$.

Comment: I appreciate the correction. I now understand ${\prec}:={\preceq}\setminus{\approx}$, where ${\approx}=\{(x,y):x\preceq y\preceq x\}$. I guess the notion of "minimal" for preorders $\preceq$ and binary relations $R$ (in the context of well-foundedness) are different.

Answer (score 2):

a is a minimal element when for all x <= a, a <= x.

The minimal elements of the preorder
x < y, y < x, x < a, y < a are x and y.

Answer (score 0):

**Definition.** Let $X$ be a set. Let $\preceq$ be a preorder in $X$. Fix $S\subseteq X$.

A $\preceq$-minimal-element of $S$ is an element $t$ of $S$ such that $(\forall s\in S)[s\preceq t\:\Rightarrow\:s=t]$.

A $\preceq$-maximal-element of $S$ is an element $t$ of $S$ such that $(\forall s\in S)[t\preceq s\:\Rightarrow\:t=s]$.